# simple html dom: find an element by matching the text inside the tag

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

i like to find a specific `h4` tag that has no class or id. i want to find that `h4` tag by the text is inside of it:

as you see below `h4` tags are inside of block tags but block tags numbers are different for each product for example some of them don't have price. so if i do this `$html->find('block[2]')` if there wasn't any price its gonna show me color instead.
so i want to say if h4 `inner text = 'Price:'` show me `$2,163` that is inside the `.block` tag. ok?

**target HTML:**

```
<div class="article" id="article">

    <div class="block">
        <h4>First name and last name:</h4>
         name name
     </div>

     <div class="block">
         <h4>Price:</h4>
          $2,163
           <span>(50% off)</span>
     </div>

     <div class="block">
          <h4>Color:</h4>
           black,
           <span>and white</span>
     </div>

     <div class="block">
           <h4>Date:</h4> 2020
     </div>
              
     <div class="block">
          <h4>Time:</h4>
          <time datetime="12">12 clock</time>
     </div>
</div>
```

**my PHP:**

```
$html = file_get_html("$url");

foreach ($html->find('#article') as $ret) {
    foreach ($ret->find('.block') as $pa) {
        foreach ($pa->find('h4') as $e) {
            if (strpos($e->innerhtml, "Price:") !== FALSE) {
                $str = $e->innerhtml;
                $price = $str->parent()->innertext;
                //$price = $str->plaintext;
                echo $price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i like to check if `<h4>Price:<h4>` exist then show the `.block` content and not with h4 included.

 but i'm getting nothing.

srry for my english

Comment: How about "Color"? Should it be just "black,"? "black, and white"?

Comment: Your question isn't clear: are you looking for the price from the `<h4>` element or the year from the `<div class="block">` element?

Comment: @Jeto and that is the another question because the ".block" tags can contain only a text or a span tag or <time> but for now let's assume i just want the black, not the span or h4.

Comment: @JackFleeting i want to see if -> h4 text =  First name..: , Price:, Color: , Date: , Time: then show h4s  parent .block tags content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like the following. It looks for any `<h4>` within an element with the `block` class within an element with the `article` ID, then checks its text. If it matches, it removes the title and returns the text of what's left in the block:

```
function findValue($html, string $key): ?string
{
    foreach ($html->find('#article .block h4') as $h4) {
        if ($h4->innertext() === "{$key}:") {
            $h4 = clone $h4;  // to prevent altering the document
            $block = $h4->parent();
            $block->removeChild($h4);

            return $block->text();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo findValue($html, 'First name and last name'), PHP_EOL;  // name name
echo findValue($html, 'Price'), PHP_EOL;                     // $2,163 (50% off)
echo findValue($html, 'Color'), PHP_EOL;                     // black, and white
echo findValue($html, 'Date'), PHP_EOL;                      // 2020
echo findValue($html, 'Time'), PHP_EOL;                      // 12 clock
```

Comment: Thank you my friend this is kinda making sense but i'm getting some kind of error in HtmlDocument and $html from findValue($html,  p.s:i am new to php

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to findValue() must be an instance of HtmlDocument, instance of simple_html_dom given, called in

Comment: @Reza Try removing the type hint on the first function arg then, I guess it depends on simplehtmldom's version. I've edited my answer.

Comment: this is great its working now, but there is a minor problem that it returns Price:$2,163 (50% off). not removing h4 child but its ok i can handle it with pregex from here. thank you for your time and help.